# How to disable laptop's internal shortcuts for rotating display?

Tags: windows-7, compaq-laptop

Laptop model: HP Compaq Presario CQ57
OS: Windows 7

How to disable Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down/Left/Right keyboard shortcuts that rotate the display (*just how many people use something like that, and for what?*)?

Comment: I've seen some people use it, for messing with people. I never thought about turning it off however, I don't think it is a Windows feature as some laptops have it and others don't (even if they are both running Windows 7).

Comment: @PlasmaPower - I was hoping they would have some useful purpose.

Comment: The screen rotations existed (primarily) for now-legacy tablets/convertibles that didn't have a way to auto-detect which was Up.  It was also intended for use with a rotated monitor (think widescreen in portrait) in cases where the monitor doesn't know/report it's been rotated.  At least that's what Intel told us back in the day. :)

Comment: The only way I see these key combinations used is to teach new colleagues to lock their PCs when leaving the desk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable this in the display adapter screen (Intel/AMD/Nvidia). 
this is not part of Windows default shutouts.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on your desktop
- Click Catalyst(TM) Control Center
- When that comes up click Hotkeys
- Click "Enable Hotkeys" to uncheck it and
  disable that feature

To answer your other question - I normally use it on other people's unsuspecting computers. ;) The reality though - I've actually seen rotated screens in use in hospitals sometimes but I haven't come across any real need to have it used all the time as you're usually not rotating your monitors multiple times in a day.